# Is there a way to generate markdown files from Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, r, markdown, jupyter

Besides html output, I would like to generate markdown documents which can be recognised by the markdown parser in bitbucket or github. 
Is there a way to generate markdown files from jupyter notebooks, similar to the 
"keep markdown source file" option in Rstudio?

Note: These answers deal with markdown output in specific code cells:

- [How to programmatically generate markdown output in Jupyter notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/how-to-programmatically-generate-markdown-output-in-jupyter-notebooks)
- [Make output cells like Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770394/make-output-cells-like-markdown)

This is not what I'm looking for. I want to generate a complete markdown.md document where code and output is available.

Comment: Is this tool kind of what you're looking for: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert

Comment: Yes thanks. I already use pandoc, but I didn't know about nbconvert.

Comment: @duckmayr, post as an answer?